# How to include C++ 17 headers with g++ 6.2.0 with -std=c++17 (optional, any, string_view, variant)

Tags: c++, include, g++, header-files, c++17

`std::optional` is in C++ 17, where it was `std::experimental::optional` before.

I tried compiling a file which included `<optional>`, with the command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 <filename>.cpp
```

(in the Bash terminal). I get the following error:

```
<filename>.cpp:5:20 fatal error: optional: No such file or directory
 #include <optional>
                    ^
compilation terminated
```

But I can `#include <experimental/optional>` just fine.

Am I missing some header files? How can I include the `optional` header?

I also can't include `<any>`, `<string_view>` or `<variant>`, getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

[GCC 6.2's support for C++17 is experimental](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html), which is literally why the headers are arranged like this.

If only they'd done this for `std::regex` back in the day! It's a gift.

<sub>https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I made a hacky workaround when faced with a situation like this:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ < 7
# include <experimental/string_view>
# define string_view experimental::string_view
#else
# include <string_view>
#endif
```