# Setting up Travis CI with CMake C++17 project

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci

I am trying to setup Travis CI with a C++17 project. We use CLion for development which means we have an automatically generated CMakeLists.txt file. I am new to compiling and running C++ from the command line.

From my understanding, everything Travis uses is outdated and will need to be updated to work with C++17. My .travis.yml so far looks like this and I'm sure it has many issues.

```
dist: trusty
sudo: require

language: cpp
compiler: gcc

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - gcc-6
      - g++-6
      - cmake

script:
  - sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
  - sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++
  - export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6
  - export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-6
  - cmake --version
  - cmake CMakeLists.txt
  - cmake  --build . --target neat
```

The build fails because one of the C++17 libraries couldn't be imported.

**EDIT** Added Travis error message.

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=feature/travis-ci https://github.com/sheldonkwoodward/bNEAT.git sheldonkwoodward/bNEAT
Cloning into 'sheldonkwoodward/bNEAT'...
remote: Counting objects: 778, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 778 (delta 9), reused 13 (delta 5), pack-reused 759
Receiving objects: 100% (778/778), 2.62 MiB | 12.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (470/470), done.
$ cd sheldonkwoodward/bNEAT
$ git checkout -qf e1827e4ca53b041322e92dc207f1e133968a69f8
$ export CXX=g++
$ export CC=gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
0.01s$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
The command "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc" exited with 0.
0.01s$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++
The command "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++" exited with 0.
0.00s$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6
The command "export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6" exited with 0.
0.00s$ export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-6
The command "export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-6" exited with 0.
0.13s$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.9.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
The command "cmake --version" exited with 0.
0.91s$ cmake CMakeLists.txt
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-6
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-6 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-6
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-6 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/travis/build/sheldonkwoodward/bNEAT
The command "cmake CMakeLists.txt" exited with 0.
0.15s$ cmake  --build . --target neat
Scanning dependencies of target neat
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/neat.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/travis/build/sheldonkwoodward/bNEAT/src/SnakeGame.hpp:9:20: fatal error: optional: No such file or directory
 #include <optional>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/neat.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/neat.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/neat.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [neat] Error 2
The command "cmake  --build . --target neat" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(neat)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp src/ANN.cpp src/ANN.hpp src/ConnectionGene.cpp src/ConnectionGene.hpp src/Gene.cpp src/Gene.h src/Node.cpp src/Node.hpp src/NEAT.cpp src/NEAT.hpp src/SnakeGame.cpp src/SnakeGame.hpp src/Snake.cpp src/Snake.hpp)


# Tests
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)
add_executable(neat ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: "The build fails because one of the C++17 libraries couldn't be imported." - 
With such description we can only *guess* what is going wrong. Please, show **exact error message**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added the full log from Travis.

Comment: Please also show your CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: @rubenvb Added CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Can you rerun that with `cmake CMakeLists.txt -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` ? Also you can just `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-6 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-6` in place of exports and symlinks.

Comment: Running `cmake CMakeLists.txt -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` locally produces the exact same output. For whatever reason, it causes Travis to stall after confirming network availability and then fails.

Comment: Looks like gcc-6 doesn't have `<optional>` header, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889414/how-to-include-c-17-headers-with-g-6-2-0-with-std-c17-optional-any-str). (The referenced question is about version 6.2, but you have 6.4. So you question is not a true duplicate).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to use gcc-7 and g++-7 to add support for std::optional. My working .travis.yml:

```
language: cpp
compiler: gcc

os: linux
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-7

script:
  - export CC=gcc-7
  - export CXX=g++-7
  - cmake --version
  - cmake CMakeLists.txt
  - cmake  --build . --target neat
```