# optional not found in g++

Tags: c++, g++, debian

I have a c++ program which is using "optional".

I have imported it with `#include <optional>` at the top of the file (line 4) and i'm compiling with the line `g++ -std=c++17 -o name.o -c source.cpp` but even so I still get this error:

```
source.cpp:4:20: fatal error: optional: No such file or directory 
 #include <optional>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

My OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) 64-bit

g++ version: 6.3.0

g++ was installed with `sudo apt -y install build-essential`

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: GCC version 6 doesn't have a full C++17 implementation.

Comment: read about that and I tried "#include <experimental/optional>" but that  would'nt compile either..

Comment: A nearly identical question has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889414/how-to-include-c-17-headers-with-g-6-2-0-with-std-c17-optional-any-str

Comment: edited the typo, thx!

Comment: g++ version 6.3.0 does not support C++17.  g++ version 6.3.0 predates C++17.  It has experimental support for some parts of (pre-standard) C++17.  GCC 8.2 is available.